# Suggest a messaging product with Caching support for latest version of each message

Tags: messaging

I am looking forward for a messaging product which can fulfil following use case.

1. Publisher can publish messages over a topic.
2. Whenever a consumer subscribes to a topic, he should first get messages published on the topic so far ( since the publisher started publishing) and onwards.
3. A message can have multiple versions. e.g. a message pertains to information for a stock. When that info changes, publisher publishes version 2 of the message. In such case, clients that connect later should see only version 2 of the message and not version 1.
4. This one is not a strict requirement but if publisher wants to delete some message from the broker cache, so that if any client connects later, he does not get some particular message in stream of previous messages.

I have looked at Red Hat MRG and Apache Active MQ products but they do seem to provide this functionality.

Red Hat Mrg Experience-

> Red Hat MRG has a feature Initial Value Exchange but that caches only
>   single message on exchange. It also offers Last Value Queues which
>   support Versioned messages but they require a queue to be created in
>   advance for a consumer. I want something dynamic so that if a new
>   subscriber connects ( about whom I do not know in advance), it should
>   be able to send latest versions of all the messages published on that
>   topic. Will really appreciate you inputs/solutions to above use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer 
This one is possible using RedHat Mrg. 
You have to use browse only queues and create consumer (that do not send ack ) to get the Initial image and updates.

Answer (score 1):

Hornetq has this feature. Other options (all commercial) include Informatica Ultra Messaging,  my channels Nirvana and solace.

Comment: can you please point out with what name these features are available in Hornetq / Informatica/ Nirvana. That will be very helpful.

Comment: Informatica would be either UMCache or particular configurations of late join. I don't have nirvana docs to hand so can't comment there. HornetQ is last-value-queue, it's in their docs (something like chapter 47 iirc). Note that your use case is almost certainly more like a dynamic destination name per type of message you want versioned.

Answer (score 0):

Actually MRG-M would support what you require. MRG-M has the concept of a last value queue. The last value queue type causes logically updated versions of previous messages to appear to overwrite the older messages.

Comment: I do not know which subscriber will be connecting in advance so I can't create a queue for him beforehand. The feature I am looking for is that client can subscribe to a topic and all latest messages since the start of publisher are replayed to him.